# Error while opening indexeddb with higher version than existing

Tags: javascript

```
var database = e.target.result;
var version =  Number(database.version);
console.log("in onsuccess>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : "+dbName);
console.log(e);     
database.close();
var secondRequest = indexedDB.open(dbName, (version+1));
console.log(secondRequest); // <-- error on this line

//console.log(secondRequest.result);
secondRequest.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
    console.log("in onupgradeneeded>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    console.log(e);     
    var database = e.target.result;
    //database.setVersion(12);
    var objectStore = database.createObjectStore(storeName, {
        keyPath: 'id'
    });
};
secondRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {
    console.log("000000000000000000000000000000");
    e.target.result.close();
};

secondRequest.onerror = function(e){
    console.log("Error ------------------- ");
    console.log(e);
}
```

in above console I am getting following error in

```
console.log(secondRequest);
```

error:

```
IDBOpenDBRequest
error   :  [Exception: DOMException]
```

I have added listner

```
IDBOpenDBRequest.onerror = function(e){
}
```

But It is not going there. Help me if anybody have solution.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have some of the core concepts down, your code is really hard to follow as is. To begin with, this `e` event assignment is undefined:

```
var database = e.target.result;
```

Where is the database `open()`? Where is `dbName` coming from?

Provide more of your failing code, preferably via [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TG98p/2/), and we'll help you find a solution.

UPDATE: [Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/taylorbuley/yxbsA/) of what you're trying to do.

**Output** `div`:

```
<div id="idb_version"></div>
```

**Code**:

```
var db_name = 'myname',
    database_open_request = window.indexedDB.open(db_name);
database_open_request.addEventListener('success', function (e) {
    database = e.target.result;
    database.close();
    var second_database_open_request = window.indexedDB.open(db_name, database.version + 1);
    second_database_open_request.addEventListener('upgradeneeded', function (e) {
        database = e.target.result;
        database.close();
        window.document.getElementById("idb_version").innerHTML = database.version;
    });
});
```

When not specifying a version param, you get a reference to the most recent version on `success` callback. Then I listen for a `versionchange` and increase the version by one. Run this over and over and you'll see the version increase one by one.

Comment: Thanks for response,I wrote a code to create new object store while version change on  http://jsfiddle.net/cLLzp/13/ .And object store is not getting created while version change.